# iframe takes focus on loading page in asp .net

Tags: asp.net, web-applications

I am using iframe for reading pdf on page load. I have alt + Q as a shortcut for toggling data pane on/off. Now the problem is that while loading page iframe takes focus from my active browser so my shortcut doesn't work until i take focus back from iframe to my current active window of that page in which i have loaded my pdf for reading.

Please find me some solution to take focus from iframe on loading page in asp.net application.

Comment: could you post some .aspx code.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried setting the focus to some other control in the main window on page load?

Comment: yes i tried to set focus on another control on page load as well but didn't worked.